# Access ZOO item id in an element template file

Tags: php, zoo

Am trying in yootheme ZOO app to enable the rating element ONLY when the date element passed the today date but i cant find a way to get the item_id. If I try for example 277 everything is working, but how i can get the specific item id for each page?

I added those lines in the beginning of /media/zoo/applications/page/elements/rating/tmpl|rating.php

```
$app = App::getInstance('zoo');
$item = $app->table->item->get(277);
$element_id = "ffc8051a-fa18-4444-916c-bfbd74e2cb4e";
$element_value = $item->getElement($element_id)->getElementData()->get('value');
$eventdate = $element_value;
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if (strtotime($eventdate) > $now) :
   echo "bla bla";
endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found it out:

```
$item_id = $this->_item->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another easy way if your data was in Array:

In teaser.php or full.php you can access any information on element with code like this:

```
<?php  
$status = $item->getElement('0e3527e4-032c-4d35-a630-7b0418eb9ecc')->getElementData()->get('option');  
print_r($status['0']);   
?>
```

In some cases, 'option' need be replced by 'value'.
You need access your data base and see the structure of element like this:

```
"0e3527e4-032c-4d35-a630-7b0418eb9ecc":  {
        "option":  {
            "0": "em-andamento"
        },
        "select": "1"
    },
```

See this other obeject structure ofr 'value' case:

```
"d9f72e0a-50d3-4be7-89f4-4d30b11aa5a1":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "2015-11-18 02:00:00"
        }
    },
```